# Exibindo aviso de 'carregando' quando iframe atualizar - html

Tags: javascript, html, html5, front-end

Estou com dificuldades em uma aplicação, onde as telas demoram para redirecionar. Para contornar o problema, criei uma página apenas com um iframe, o qual contém a navegação entre as páginas.

O problema maior é que não é possível deixar as trocas de janelas mais rápidas, pois as mesmas ficam armazenadas em um CLP Siemens s7-1200.

Então, surgiu a idéia de quando o usuário trocar de página dentro do iframe, seja exibido uma mensagem que está carregando.

Ou seja, toda vez que o **conteúdo do frame atualizar**, deverá aparecer uma mensagem de carregando.

Para isso posso utilizar JavaScript e html.

Abaixo segue código da página inicial:

```
<iframe  id="ifr"  src="inicial.html" width="99.8%" border="0" height="800" ></iframe>
```

Dentro do iframe, existe menus para navegações para outras páginas, dentro do iframe.

Comment: É bom sempre postar alguma parte relevante do código, facilita bastante o entendimento da pergunta e uma possível resposta rápida e precisa. Senão gera mts comentários com pedidos de mais explicações.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, a página contem um frame onde as páginas mudam dentro frame, ou seja, a URL no navegador continua a mesma?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Dvdsamm. Porém, cada vez que as páginas mudam dentro do iframe, preciso que seja exibida uma mensagem de carregando. Pois a troca entre páginas é lenta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É preciso fazer uma estrutura de comunicação entre o frame e a janela principal, verificando quando um link de navegação dentro do frame for clicado e quando o frame for carregado. Para isso, é preciso adicionar uma classe para cada link nas páginas do frame, por exemplo:

```
<a class="navega" href=""></a>
```

Em seguida adicione um atributo `onload` na tag do frame que irá chamar a função `onLoadHandler()` quando o mesmo for carregado:

```
<iframe onload="onLoadHandler()" src=""></iframe>
```

No código da página que contém o frame (página-mãe), adicione o JS abaixo com as funções necessárias:

```
<script>
window.Carregar = function(){
    var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
    elemDiv.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:100;background:#000;color:#fff;';
    elemDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Carregando..."));
    elemDiv.setAttribute("id", "carregando");
    document.body.appendChild(elemDiv);
}

function onLoadHandler() {
    var element = document.getElementById("carregando");
    if(element){
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
}
</script>
```

Em cada página a ser carregada dentro do frame (páginas-filhas), adicione o código:

```
<script>
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("navega");
function myFunction() {
    window.parent.Carregar();
}
for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
</script>
```

Sempre que um link com a classe *navega* for clicado dentro do frame, irá exibir uma div "Carregando..." na janela principal. Quando o frame terminar de ser carregado, essa div será eliminada.